# Installed Brother MFC-L3770CDW driver but still can't print

Tags: drivers, printing, brother

Driver installed ok (using driver install tool from https://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadhowto.aspx?c=nz&lang=en&prod=mfcl3770cdw_us_eu_as&os=128&dlid=dlf006893_000&flang=4&type3=625) and I could add the driver to my installed printer but files still wouldn't print. I am using wireless network connection between computer and printer. On the printer "job list", it's stuck on "Pending". When selecting which printer to use (there is a CUPS-BRF version, BrotherLaserjet...MFC-L3770CDW as well as the MFC-L3770CDW version of the installed printer to choose from). When selecting "Print" from the file to be printed, next to the MFC-L3770CDW installed printer it says "Waiting for printer to become available.". I've tried restarting (several times), the IP address of the printer is set correctly and the Brother driver is installed. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up resolving my own problem by entering sudo apt install lprng in the terminal (and entering my password). After this I was able to print using all the versions of my installed printer.